# Accumulation points, topology

Tags: general-topology

Show that in a topological space $(X;\tau)$; if $(\left\lbrace{x}\right\rbrace')'$ is closed and $x \in (A')'$, then $x \in A'$

Using the definition, for all $V \in E_x$, were $E_x$ is the set which contains all neighborhoods of $x$; $A' \cap V-\left\lbrace{x}\right\rbrace \neq \emptyset; x \in V$.

Also I have $X-\left\lbrace{x}\right\rbrace' \in \tau.$ With that I can deduce that for every $V \in E_x; V-\left\lbrace{x}\right\rbrace'$ is a neighborhood for a $y \in C \subseteq V$, were $C \in \tau$; so $V \in E_y$. That's all I can extract from the problem. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I recall that a point $x$ in a a topological space $X$ is called an *accumulation point* of a set $A\subset X$ if $x\in \overline{A\setminus\{x\}}$; the set of all accumulation points of $A$ is called the *derived set* of $A$ (see, for instance, [E, 1.3.2]). If $A’$ denotes the derived set of $A$ then the claim is wrong. Indeed, let $X$ be a set $\{1,2,3\}$ endowed with the antidiscrete topology $\tau=\{X,\varnothing\}$, $x=1$, and $A=\{x\}$. Then $\{x\}’=A’=\{b,c\}$ and a set $(\{x\}’)’=(A’)’=\{a,b,c\}$ is closed, but $x\in (A’)’\setminus A’$.

*References*

[E] Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.